# Using hooks vs. wrapping commands in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

What are the relative pros and cons for using hooks vs. using an extension that wraps a command for a particular task?

In other words, what are the criteria for deciding whether to use hooks or wrap a command?

Please also list the cases where one approach is the only option. One case I can think of is to add new arguments for existing commands. You could also change/remove arguments, for example I default `log` to `log -g` but `graphlog` aborts in the presence of some "incompatible" arguments (see `graphlog.check_unsupported_flags`), so I added a `log` wrapper to remove `-g` in those cases, because forced abortion is a crime against humanity.

It feels like hooks are more clean-cut. Python hooks run in the hg process so there's no performance issue. And while it's easy to use `extensions.wrapcommand` to create command wrappers, it's trivial to create/disable hooks, and to adjust the order in which they are applied (they should be self-contained in the first place).

And here's a quote from [hgrc doc](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hooks) that recommends standard hooks over pre/post command hooks, but it also applies to hooks over wrapper:

> ... hooks like "commit" will be called in all contexts that generate a commit (e.g. tag) and not just the commit command.

Also I guess that hooks are not subjected to GPL (or are they?), whereas command wrappers in [extensions are](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/License#What_is_a_.22derived_work.22.3F_Is_an_extension_a_derived_work.3F).

(I hope a 1.5k+ user can create a `mercurialhooks` tag. Git fan boys have beaten us with `githooks`.)

Comment: retagged, but changed the name slightly to match the conventions.

Comment: @Niall: thanks! I guess the git boys don't care much about conventions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't speak to licensing issues, but the biggest difference between a hook and an extension is that a hook can be written in any language whereas extensions are always python.

If one's writing in python then there's little difference between a hook and an extension:

- either can delve deeply into mercurial internals
- both require users modify their `.hgrc` to enable them
- both can wrap/intercept commands

I think your log command argument modification could be done with a `pre-log` hook in addition to being done as an extension.

TL;DR: If you're writing in python there's little difference, and if you're not hooks are your only option.

Comment: Thanks for the important, albeit obvious (to me) difference. But how do you remove command argument in a hook? I tried a pre-log hook like this: `def prelogHook(ui, repo, **kwargs): print kwargs` and it only shows `{'args': 'log', 'hooktype': 'pre-log'}` when I default `log` to `log -g`.

Comment: I'm not certain where, but I suspect there's a reference path to them through the ui object.  In a shell hook you could just check the `$HG_OPTS` for incompatible options, remove `-g` if they're found, and re-run the `hg log` command with the new arg-set, and then return -1.  Not totally elegant, but achieving the goal from a totally external hook.